# Why are so many wireless mice using USB dongles these days?

Tags: usb, mouse, dongle, wireless-mouse

I've been noticing that increasingly mice seem to be coming as wireless mice with USB RF dongles. Why are manufacturers emphasizing proprietary **dongles** instead of USB wired or Bluetooth?

Comment: In my experience, Bluetooth devices do *not* always remember the pairing. On the other hand, USB RF dongles work reliably for me. But perhaps it's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Number one factor is simply **convenience**.

People like going wireless, you could re-post this question and ask, why are people using wireless internet more these days? Same answer.

Its convenient to go wireless, and most people don't consider a battery in these devices to be a problem, as most come with charging cradles or offer easy charge methods.

Comment: It's convenient for the manufacturer because they don't have to print manuals and support how to pair the mice with Bluetooth on every other OS.

Comment: Dongles are not, have never been, and will never be, convenient.

Comment: They are also convenient because host OS doesn't even need to know about Bluetooh. How would someone install say Windows with a Bluetooth mouse? Furthermore dongles are often more reliable than Bluetooth precisely because they avoid all problems that are related to Bluetooth. For I understand that for some sparing one more USB port for the mouse may be too much (especially if you only have say two o a netbook), but in many applications mice with proprietary dongles are irreplaceable.

Comment: Bluetooth interfaces are not common hardware on many consumer computers. Therefor, USB is far more convenient as it is more common.

Comment: Dongles are far more convenient than wires.

Comment: Correct, people are not concerned with the USB interface; they just want to get rid of yet another messy cable to the desktop or laptop computer.